# C++ "Segmentation fault" or "free(): invalid pointer" depending on input (reproducible)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, valgrind

This program gives a "Segmentation fault" or a "free(): invalid pointer" based on the input file used. The bug is reproducible.

This is very strange especially because `free` is *not* called.

Here is the complete program.

```
// Open a file, read line by line,
// and for each (loooong) line, fraction it into
// small, justified lines.
// Justification done by adding spaces to existing spaces.

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>
#include <functional>

const int pageWidth = 50; // max width for a (justified) line

typedef std::vector<std::string> WordList;
typedef std::vector<int> SpaceList;

// ========
// HELPERS
// ========

// Helper to return "cccccc...ccc"
std::string repeat (const int n, char c) {
    std::string ret;
    for (int i{0}; i < n; ++i) {
        ret += c;
    }
    return ret;
}

// "Random" int between min and max (pseudo-random: reproducible)
unsigned int random_pred(std::size_t salt, unsigned int min, unsigned int max) {
    unsigned int output = min + (salt % static_cast<int>(max - min + 1));
    return output;
}

// alpha is greater at center
float alpha_weight(float z) { return std::max(100*(sin(z))*(sin(z)), float(1)); }

// Weight of a space, ie probability to add here blank space
int weight(int x, unsigned int l)
{
    float z = 3.141 * x / l;
    return alpha_weight(z);
}

// line -> vector of words
WordList splitTextIntoWords( const std::string &text )
{
    WordList words;
    std::istringstream in(text);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(words));
    return words;
}

// ======
// CORE
// ======

// Give each space a weight, a 'probability' to be expanded
SpaceList charge_spaces ( int l, const WordList & words, SpaceList spp) 
{
    SpaceList sp_weights;
    std::string p{ words[0] }, h;
    int wg;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size()-1; ++i) {
            wg = weight(spp[i], l);
            sp_weights.push_back(wg);
    }
    return sp_weights;
}

// Given weighted list of spaces positions, 'randomly' pick one
int random_sp( const SpaceList& spw, std::size_t salt ) {
    std::string m;
    unsigned int i{48}, total{0}; // ASCII 48 = ' '
    for (const int & n : spw) {
        char ch = static_cast<char>(i); // '1'; '2'; '3' ...
        std::string segment = repeat(n, ch); // "11"; "2222"; "3333333333333" ....
        m += segment;
        total += n;
        ++i;
    }  // now, m like "11112222222222333333333333333333334444444455555", of length <total>
    int mqrh = random_pred(salt, 0, total); // Get 0 <= random <= total
    char iss = m[mqrh]; // Read the char at this position (for example, more likely '3' here)
    int ret = static_cast<int>(iss) - 48; // Example: '3' -> 3
    return ret; // Example: return 3
}

// Add spaces to a (small) line, to justify it.
// We need to expand it by <excess> spaces.
std::string justifyLine( std::string line, WordList ww, SpaceList space_positions, int excess )
{
    SpaceList spwg = charge_spaces(line.size(), ww, space_positions);
    SpaceList spadd{spwg.begin(), spwg.end()}; // number of spaces to add after word <i>
    for (size_t k = 0; k < ww.size()-1; ++k) {
        spadd[k] = 1; // By default, 1 space after each word
    }
    int winner; // Which space will win additional space ?
    std::size_t str_hash = std::hash<std::string>{}(line) / 1000; // 'random' seed, reproducible
    for (int i{0}; i < excess; ++i) { // Where to add these <excess> needed spaces ?
        std::size_t salt = str_hash + 37*i;
        winner = random_sp(spwg, salt);
        spadd[winner] = spadd[winner] + 1; // space after <winner> word is incremented !
        spwg[winner] = std::max( spwg[winner] / 10, 1); // Weight of winner is decreased
    }
    // Build up the justified line
    std::string justified;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ww.size()-1; ++j) {
        justified.append(ww[j]); // Add next word
        justified.append(spadd[j], ' '); // Add few spaces
    }
    justified.append(ww.back()); // Add last word
    std::cout << justified << std::endl;
    return justified;
}

// Fraction a long line in several justified small lines
void justifyText( const std::string& text )
{
    WordList words = splitTextIntoWords(text);
    std::string line;
    WordList ww;
    SpaceList space_positions;
    int position{0};
    int nwords_in_line{0};
    for (const std::string& word : words) {
        size_t s = word.size();
        if (line.size() + s + 1 <= pageWidth) { // next word fit into the line.
            if (!line.empty()) {
                line.append(" ");
                space_positions.push_back(position++);
            }
            line.append(word);
            nwords_in_line++;
            ww.push_back(word); // append this word to the list
            position += s;
        } else { // build a justified small line from the words added up
            justifyLine(line, ww, space_positions, pageWidth - position);
            line.clear(); // Cleaning for next chunk
            ww.clear();
            space_positions.clear();
            line = word;
            position = s;
            nwords_in_line = 1;
            ww.push_back(word); // don't forget the last word (that overflowed)
        }
    }
    std::cout << line << std::endl; // Remaining of the long line
}

// =====
// main
// =====
int main () {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile ("candle.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline(myfile,line) )
        {
            justifyText(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else std::cerr << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

File "candle.txt" is an ASCII text file, [here](https://zerobin.net/?1839e9933c67476f#lxeDerVKLer7KonjRo2vjgj1nOujRBpcSIJr86aoLEo=) is a copy.

The whole file gives `free(): invalid pointer`, always at same position -- see below **(1)**

If cutting between the two markups in the PREFACE (deleting the chunk between the two `CUT HERE`marks), program gives a `Segmentation fault`.

Running with Valgrind gives this (very strange because `repeat` function does not seem problematic)

```
Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 4487)
==4487==    at 0x4838DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:342)
==4487==    by 0x4990859: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==4487==    by 0x4990F34: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==4487==    by 0x10A406: repeat[abi:cxx11](int, char) (in /home/fig/Documents/cpp/cil)
==4487==    by 0x10A8DD: random_sp(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, unsigned long) (in /home/fig/Documents/cpp/cil)
==4487==    by 0x10AB34: justifyLine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int) (in /home/fig/Documents/cpp/cil)
==4487==    by 0x10AF71: justifyText(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /home/fig/Documents/cpp/cil)
==4487==    by 0x10B195: main (in /home/xxx/Documents/cpp/cil)
```

Any idea welcome

**(1) End of output:**

```
We have several tests for oxygen  besides the mere
burning of bodies. You have seen a candle burnt in
oxygen, or in the air;   you have  seen phosphorus
burnt in the air, or in oxygen; and  you have seen
iron-filings  burnt in  oxygen. But we  have other
tests besides  these, and  I am about  to refer to
one or two  of them for  he purpose of  carrying
```

Comment: Hmm, odd that `repeat` is crashing.  You could replace it with `std::string repeat (const int n, char c) { return n > 0 ? std::string(n, c) : std::string(); }`.  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: [How are you able to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/1v4xEfjnq) `weight(spp[i], l, words[i], words[i+1]);` when that function takes **two** parameters?

Comment: Now that you have compiled this re-simplified code, I hope you have then confirmed that this exact code also produces the errors you are describing?

Comment: valgrind is giving a completely different fail, on line 109, invalid read.

Comment: @Eljay Program crashes now (`free(): invalid pointer`) at another point. Valgrind still reports `repeat`.

Comment: On line 109, ` spadd[winner] = ...` winner is -48, according to my gdb. This is not going to end well.

Comment: It is completely irrelevant exactly where it crashes. The first instance of what valgrind flags is undefined behavior. From that point on, demons will fly out of your nose, and they will continue flying until the program crashes. The problem is not the program crashing, but demons flying out of your nose. You've been focusing on completely the wrong thing.

Comment: The shown code is very fragile and error prone. The `-48` comes from this line: `char iss = m[mqrh];`. `m` is a `std::string`. There is absolutely nothing obvious, insofar as how `mqrh` is calculated,  that explicitly guarantees that it does not exceed `m.size()-1`. This is most likely an assumption or an expectation based on some unspecified factors, that I don't have the time to track down, but somewhere the assumptions were wrong, and the whole house of cards comes crashing down, somewhere else.

Comment: Once the Bad Thing™ happens, anything after that point is just happenstance careening and digitally blindfolded parkour.  If you're lucky, the program crashes.  But if you are particularly unlucky, the program appears to work.

Comment: Looking at that whole function, `total` should always be equal to `m.size()`. Get rid of it completely. You know that `random_pred`'s 3rd parameter should be the maximum value, and not one past it. Therefore, if `m.size()-1` instead of `total` would've been right, and foolproof. The best way to prevent these kinds of bugs is to make it logically impossible for them to happen. It is logically impossible to have this kind of off-by-one bug by always passing `m.size()-1` (except if `m` is an empty string, then hillarity ensues, but that's a different subject).

Comment: You could also make the problem never happen by using iterators and std::distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash occurs as a result of a consequence from an earlier bug. There's nothing (directly) wrong with any of the code in your backtrace. Although the bug effectively was traced to one of the function the actual crash was triggered from an earlier invocation of the same code, and the actual bug would be triggered later, after returning from the point of the crash.

One of my stock comments starts with: "Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way." This is followed by explanation that a minimal reproduce example must be provided, which you mostly did. This allowed the problem to be reproduced trivially. The first instance of undefined behavior occured elsewhere, on line 109:

```
        spadd[winner] = spadd[winner] + 1;
```

valgrind has a very useful option: `--vgdb-error=1`. This stops execution immediately when valgrind detects memory corruption, on this line, in this case. valgrind then gives instruction for attaching to the current process, with `gdb`. Doing so immediately led to the observation that this value of `winner` was -48. Modifying `spadd[-48]` will only result in tears.

At this point it wasn't too difficult to backtrack to line 91, where `-48` came from, which led to the actual bug, an off by 1:

```
int mqrh = random_pred(salt, 0, total);
```

`total` here was always the same as `m.size()`, and this duplicate logic resulted in the bug, since this parameter should be the last value in the range for `random_pred`, and not one past it. The expected results here is to pick a random character from `m`, so the valid range is `0` to `m.size()-1`. If it wasn't for the duplicated logic, being mindful of how `random_pred()`'s parameters must be defined, the last parameter would've naturally be `m.size()-1`. But the duplicated logic resulted in an indirect reference to the underlying value, `total`, and this detail was forgot.

Another contributing factor to common kinds of bugs is going against the natural flow of how C++ defines ranges and sequences: not by the minimum and the maximum value, but the minimum and one past the maximum value. `std::string::size()`, `std::vector::size`, et. al., is one past the last valid index of the underlying container, and not the last valid index of the container. Similarly, `end()`, the ending iterator is not the iterator for the last value in the sequence, but the iterator to the next, non-existent value in the sequence, "one past it".

If `random_pred` was designed in harmony with the rest of the C++ library, its formula would simply involve `min + salt % (max-min)` instead of `min + salt % (max-min+1)`. Then it wouldn't matter if its third parameter was `total` or `m.size()`, it would've naturally worked either way.